# jQuery fileupload issue

Tags: jquery, reactjs

We are initialising jQuery fileupload in componentDidMount of our react app like below:

```
$('#' + fileUploadElementId).fileupload({
      url: url,
      singleFileUploads: true,
      dropZone: $(dropZone)
    })
```

Later on in one of our action.js file we are modifying the file context as we had to add some formData and then triggering submit like below:

```
file.context.submit()
    .done(() => { // done was success
      console.log('Inside Done');
      return success();
    })
    .fail(function (res) { //fail was error
      if (res.status === 200) {
        return success();
      }
```

We were on jquery 2.x and jquery.fileupload.js was pretty old. And it was working fine. Now for security reasons we updated to jquery 3.x and downloaded jquery.fileupload.js related files from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

[image: New jQuery file-upload files]

jQuery ui widget factory was not added as jquery-ui has been updated to new version too.

After this update the file is not getting uploaded to the specified URL. Can somebody help me out in figuring what is wrong here.

Thanks in advance.